# problem with using button.setPressed(false); in android java code

Tags: java, android, user-interface, button

I want to disable the button press on a 2nd click, so I have this code for the action handler of the button in my android code :

```
      // do something when the button is clicked

       public void onClick(View v) {

        final Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.radio_red);

        if(button.isPressed()==true && rt1==true ) 

        {

            button.setPressed(false);

            button.clearFocus();

            //rt1=false;

                    //do some processing !     

        }

        else rt1=true;

    }'
```

However, button.setPressed(false);   doesnt work as expected. :(

Can anyone please help me out ?

Comment: What do you expect from button.setPressed(false) and what are you getting?

Comment: I expect this line to set the pressed state of the button to false. I am not getting that right now. If I press the button thrice, this handler should not go into the 1st loop, right ? and on the 2nd press of the button, the UI should sow the button as not pressed, right ? Thats not happening here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

button.setChecked(false);

this is the line that un-checks the radio button !!!

thanks to everyone who tried to help. :)

-
ahsan

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace the entire code with `button.setClickable(false)` - that way, your onClick() handler will be called the first time it is clicked, but any subsequent click won't do anything.

Personally, I think it's better UI design if you call `button.setEnabled(false)` - that makes it obvious to the user that the button cannot be pressed.

Comment: What I want to do is this : When you click/press on the button once, its selected/pressed, you click/press another time and it gets deselected/unpressed ! Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: well, it works like toggle button, but the outlook is of a radio button ! (you can choose and un-choose the selection!!!) I want the GUI to look like a radio button !

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you not using RadioButton then?

Comment: because, even then its not working, the button is not getting  un-pressed :(

Comment: i guess it works now....donno why it was not working earlier..thanks :)... btw, is there a way to change the radio button image ?

Comment: Look here, under Custom Button: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html